# Updating Style From WP Options Setting Page

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, theme-options, settings-api

Can you please let me know how I can set a function to update change the style like any CSS class from the setting option page? For example I have some `<P>` elements with a class name `.impo`. Now, I would like to change the color of the class to red when the checkbox has been checked and to default color when un-checked.

What I have is:

```
<?php
 add_action('admin_menu', 'fwds_plugin_settings');
 function fwds_plugin_settings() {
 add_menu_page('Price Display', 'Price Display', 'administrator', 'fwds_settings', 'fwds_display_settings');
 }
function fwds_display_settings() {
$html = '<div class="wrap"><form action="options.php" method="post" name="options">
    <h2>Change The .impo Colors</h2>
    ' . wp_nonce_field('update-options') . '
  <p>
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>Change Color To Red </td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="fwds_autoplay" value="enabled" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" /></form></div>';
echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to solve this with jQuery. If [`checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) -> [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), if not -> [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Here's how to enqueue your JS file:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'fwds_plugin_settings');

function fwds_plugin_settings() {
    $hook = add_menu_page(
        'Price Display', 
        'Price Display', 
        'add_users', 
        'fwds_settings', 
        'fwds_display_settings'
    );
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$hook", 'fwds_print_scripts' );
}
function fwds_print_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script( 
         'my-fx' 
        , plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/my-fx.js'
        , array( 'jquery' ) // Dependencies
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-fx' );
}
```

And `my-fx.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{   
    alert('my page');
});
```